# jQuery click event not working on HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a lot of trouble trying to add text to an existing `<p>` element using jQuery.  I have tried many different methods but nothing has worked so far.  Here is the code for the html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="index1.js"></script>

    <title>Drinking Game</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <button id="creategame" >Create game</button>
    <p id="demo">Hello</p> 
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#creategame').click(function(){
    $("#demo").append("Test");
  });
});
  </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where's `jquery.min.js`?

Comment: My guess is you don't load jQuery file, and the console has *$ is not defined* error.

Comment: What do I do to solve this?

Comment: The code works well, see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m3xwk6t4/1/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you don't load jQuery file, and the console has

> $ is not defined

error. Simply, add

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to `<head>` tag

```
<head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="index1.js"></script>
     <title>Drinking Game</title>
</head>
```

Comment: Such a simple fix.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the jQuery file. Add this code `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` to your file above the `<script src="index1.js"></script>`. Make sure it's above it because if it's not then you can't call the jQuery functions in the your index1.js file.

Answer (score -1):

try using the .html() function:

```
$("#demo").html("Test");
```

Answer (score -1):

The following worked for me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id='createGame' class="btn btn-default">Click</button>
    <p id="demo">Hello</p> 

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#createGame").click(function(){
              $("#demo").append("Test");
           }); 
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You need to reference jQuery in a `<script>` tag somewhere.